# Printing Large Amounts of Text on MacOS Terminal

Tags: macos, printing, terminal

I have a script that will print `5,000,000` lines of text.

Will this crash my Terminal? Is there a limit to how many lines the MacOS Terminal can handle?

What are your suggestions–alternative options–for printing large amounts of text?

Comment: Depending on which shell you use - I think OS X defaults to 'zsh' now - redirect your stdout (and perhaps stderr) to a file you can view at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the buffer/scrollback should be limited to 10.000 (afaik). It most likely will not crash. But why you want to do this in the first place? If you want to work with it better pipe it out in a text file?

Comment: You're right, I ended up printing it in a text file. Thank you Cyn.